# Assign lot numbers specific to value in excel when values aren't always known in advance

Tags: excel, sorting, excel-formula

I've been looking for hours on this I can't really come up with anything that's going to work. Hopefully I can gain some insight here.

Here is the problem guys. I'm trying to come up with a better solution for sorting inventory. The particular items have bar codes on them so I figured it would be easy to hop in excel and plug away. The problem that I'm running into is that I can't really figure out how to assign a "lot" or "location" number for a specific item and be able to reuse that if it comes up later. For example:

```
Model Input     Location
st1000dm003     1
ST336706LC      2
st1000dm003     1
st1000dm004     3
ST336705LC      4
st1000dm003     1
```

Preferably, the numbering would start at 1 and move up. The group of items in column A might not always be the same, so a table with the model number and the location will not work. It has to be able to tell if it's seen that before and what number was assigned or assign a new one if it has not been seen. The other issue that I'd most likely run into, is that I'd like to be able to run this on Office Mobile for Office 365 on Android at some point. Any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming row 1 is a header row and actual data starts in row 2, put this in cell B2 and copy down:

```
=IF(A2="","",IF(COUNTIF(A$1:A1,A2)>0,VLOOKUP(A2,A$1:B1,2,FALSE),MAX(B$1:B1)+1))
```

Comment: This will be perfect to get off of the ground. Is there a way to use this or modify it in some way so that it only counts when there are  values in column A?

Comment: Add a new IF condition in front to check if A2 is blank: `=IF(A2="","",IF(COUNTIF(A$1:A1,A2)>0,VLOOKUP(A2,A$1:B1,2,FALSE),MAX(B$1:B1)+1))`

Comment: Probably because when you copy/paste it, it is copying an extra space and illegal character (due to the code formatting within comments on this site).  Just delete the last two characters and it should work fine.  I'll also edit the answer to make it easier to copy/paste so you can use that